# Android SoundPool sometimes plays sound twice when loop param is set to 0

Tags: android, audio

Here is what I'm doing:

```
private SoundPool pool;
private int soundId;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  // new SoundPool with three channels, STREAM_MUSIC, default quality
  pool = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

  // load sound with current context, click resource, priority 1
  soundId = pool.load(this, R.raw.click, 1);

  // originally I wasn't using this but it seemed to help a bit
  // set no loop for soundId
  pool.setLoop(soundId, 0);
}

private void play()
{
  Log.v(TAG, "Play the sound once!");

  // half volume L & R, priority 1, loop 0, rate 1
  pool.play(soundId, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0, 1);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
  super.onDestroy();

  // release the pool
  pool.release();
}
```

Originally I was using a .wav file for the click sound and the problem would occur 90% of the time.  I added setLoop and it appears to reduce it a tiny bit.

I thought it might be a problem with loading .wav files so I converted the file to .mp3.  Now the problem happens 5% of the time, but it still happens.  I built with and without the setLoop call and it appears that including it helps a tiny bit.

As you can see I have added a debug log message to ensure that I am not accidentally calling the play function twice.  According to the log output, the sound is only played once but I hear the sound twice.

I have also used several different sound files.  Some of the files seem to repeat more frequently than others.  I don't see any correlations except it happens more frequently with .wav files.

I see the problem happening on Samsung Continuum running 2.1 (min & target API: level 7).  I haven't experienced any extra looping with any market apps I've downloaded on the same device.  Unfortunately, I don't have other devices to test with.

I have only found one other person experiencing this issue and he or she was also using a Samsung device.

Here is a link to the other issue reported:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/4873995/695336

At this point I guess I'll try making a release build to see if it still happens and then maybe convert to .ogg format.  After that I'll probably try switching to MediaPlayer to see if I get the same results.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Converting to ogg appears to solve this issue.  Thanks to zas.  I wonder if this is a bug specific to eclair?